# Regex to return lines starting with specific pattern in a text file

Tags: python, string, startswith

Here is my text file:

```
    --- config-archive/2022-12-21/R1.txt

+++ new

@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@

 Building configuration...
 
-Current configuration : 1106 bytes
+Current configuration : 1089 bytes
 !
 version 12.4
 service timestamps debug datetime msec
@@ -94,7 +94,7 @@

 !
 !
 !
-banner motd ^Cthis is changed through config pushing script^C
+banner motd ^Cyoyoyoyo i just changed this^C
 !
 line con 0
  exec-timeout 0 0
```

I need the program to return lines starting with a single - or + from the text file.

My approach is looping through the file and search the pattern as a string which I do not find to be efficient. So need regex to do it in an efficient way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds awfully like an AB question, but here's your solution using RegEx:

`^[-+].+`

- `^`: Matches start of the line
- `[-+]`: Matches a minus or a plus
- `.+`: Matches any character after that until the end of the line

Consider using just Python though- it might be faster, and definitely easier to read:

```py
data = " ... "

lines = [line for line in data.splitlines()
         if line.startswith('+') or line.startswith('-')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I decided to use regex because it is easier to get the result. I was able to get the desired result.

Comment: Glad to help @SuperMaxLv4 :) if my answer was correct, please mark it with the check mark on the left

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import re

pattern = r'^[-+](?![-+])'  # Match lines that start with a single `-` or `+` and do not have a `- and +` immediately after

with open('your_text_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.match(pattern, line):
            print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I was able to get the desired result.

Comment: @SuperMaxLv4 np ;)